# Selector highlight not working with LinearLayout

Tags: android, xml, selector

I need my selector `sign_out_btn_selector.xml` to highlight my linear when touched. But my selector is only changing the background color of the linear `sign_out_btn` and, keep the color on touched as default.

**main.xml**

```
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/sign_out_btn"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/sign_out_btn_selector"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:src="@drawable/outline_logout_24"
                        android:tint="#ffcecece" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Sign out"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:padding="8dp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="24dp"
                        android:layout_height="24dp"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:src="@drawable/outline_chevron_right_24" />
                </LinearLayout>
```

**sign_out_btn_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/yellow_highlight" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/yellow"/>
</selector>
```

**colors.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <!-- Light Mode -->
    <color name="black">#000000</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="yellow">#FFFF00</color>
    <color name="yellow_highlight">#7fffff00</color>
    <color name="bg_color">#FFFFFF</color>

</resources>
```

Comment: Layout does not have state `state_selected` .. you need to use `state_pressed`